# SQL Server Trigger - Prevent row update if column IsLocked BIT is true

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016, database-trigger

**SQL Server 2016 accessed by ASP.NET 4.6.2 MVC web application**

I have table "Building" and a Building can have multiple "Components". For example, Building1 has Component1 and Component2  ... etc

It was requested of me to be able to lock a building. Lock means that a component can no longer be modified (CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE). Well, as you can imagine, this is a huge application and a component can be modified in 100+ places. No one can even answer the question, "Where all do I need to lock?".

My thought is to lock everywhere I can think of and then as a safety net create a SQL Trigger that prevents all modifications if the column on the Component table "IsLocked BIT" is true. Currently, the only way I know if a component is locked is if the IsLocked column equals true.

So, I say all of that for this. How do I create a SQL Server Trigger that prevents a row of data from being modified if the row being modified has column IsLocked = 1?

**Edit 1**
In my opinion, this is not a duplicate. Using Instead of Delete or Instead of... will not work for me. If I do the instead of ... then inside of that I will need to provide commit logic. I don't want to provide commit logic. I just want to run a check prior to insert, update, delete.

**Edit 2 - Instead of Update/Delete is best choice**
If instead of... is my best choice than can someone rewrite what I have using the instead of update/delete? I don't know how to do it. Please keep in mind that requests will be coming from a web app. I won't know if they are updating one column or the entire entity or what they will passing in. I know that the way I have it written that it will catch any insert/update/delete and prevent it if locked. If there is a better way then please write it and explain why it is better.

Comment: `Instead of delete` trigger.  This is almost definitely a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preventing a specific record from being deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037243/preventing-a-specific-record-from-being-deleted)

Comment: Instead of update/delete is your best choise. Sure, you will have to write the update or delete statement inside the trigger, but it shouldn't be much longer then the code you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PreventLockedModification]
ON [dbo].[Component]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --DETERMINE INSERT(I) UPDATE(U) OR DELETE(D)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DECLARE @action as char(1);

    SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        SET @action = 
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
            END
    END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @ErrorMsg nvarchar(100) = 'This row is locked and cannot be updated';
    DECLARE @IsLocked bit;
    DECLARE @BuildingId bigint;
    DECLARE @UnitId bigint;
    DECLARE @IsComplete_Building bit;
    DECLARE @IsComplete_Unit bit;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF @action = 'U' or @action = 'D'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @IsLocked = IsLocked FROM deleted;
            IF @IsLocked = 1
                BEGIN
                    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, 16, 1);
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                END
        END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ELSE IF @action = 'I'
        BEGIN
            SELECT @BuildingId = BuildingId FROM inserted;
            SELECT @UnitId = UnitId FROM inserted;

            SELECT @IsComplete_Building = IsComplete FROM Building WHERE BuildingId = @BuildingId
            SELECT @IsComplete_Unit = IsComplete FROM Unit WHERE UnitId = @UnitId

            IF @IsComplete_Building = 1 or @IsComplete_Unit = 1
                BEGIN
                    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, 16, 1);
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                END
        END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



END
```